# Is the Higgs vacuum expectation value scale-independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, higgs

Like the title of the question states, I'd like to know if the Higgs vacuum expectation value is RG scale independent, or in other words, is it an observable. For instance, if we compute the position of the minimum of the Higgs quartic potential $\displaystyle V(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\frac{1}{4}\lambda\phi^4$, we obtain that for $m^2<0$, or the VEV, the minimum is located at $v^2=-\frac{m^2}{\lambda}$. However, the $m^2$ and $\lambda$ here are just input parameters, and ultimately depend on the RG scale $\mu$, so naively it seems that it does depend on it. On the other hand, it could be that the dependencies cancel out, and we're left with something scale independent, not to mention that the term "VEV" seems to imply it's the 1-point correlator which should be observable, and thus scale-independent. Which one is it?

Comment: note that $v$ is **not** defined as $v^2=-m^2/\lambda$, but as $v=\langle\phi\rangle$, and so it **is** the one-point function. The expression $v^2=-m^2/\lambda$ is the tree-level prediction, but it is subject to loop corrections.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That looks like an answer to me ;)

Comment: I agree with @ACuriousMind, but if you could also show if there's a a mathematical relationship between $\langle\phi\rangle$ and the tree level $v$, that'd be awesome.